# wordpress 403 forbidden erroe

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have wordpress installed on one of my clients domain, the wordpress installation is in root directory. The site was working fine but from yesterday it is giving the following error.

[image]

Please help to solve this problem.
this is htaccess

```
 # For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews Indexes ExecCGI
Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch MultiViews Indexes ExecCGI

AddType application/x-httpd-cgi .root

AddHandler cgi-script .root
AddHandler cgi-script .root
```

Added this default wordpress rules but still same error

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Post your root .htaccess file content.

Comment: # For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews Indexes ExecCGI
Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch MultiViews Indexes ExecCGI

AddType application/x-httpd-cgi .root

AddHandler cgi-script .root
AddHandler cgi-script .root

Comment: Post it in the question not in the comment please.

Comment: please check i have updated

Comment: It is obviously missing default WP rewrite rules and that might be the reason.

Comment: added default wordpress rules but still same error.

Comment: Does `/index.php` exist and readable?

Comment: Try adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` line on top.

Comment: Contact an admin who can investigate it since from outside we can only guess.